# how to change cocos2d default font

Tags: fonts, cocos2d-iphone

Apologies if this sounds very trivial, I've just not found a solution. I used Glyph Designer to create custom font for my game. It generated the .png and fnt accordingly. How can I set the newly created font as the default font?

Comment: There's no such things as the "default" font. To use the bitmap font, create a CCBitmapFont object with your font. Where necessary, replace existing labels (ie CCLabelTTF) with CCBitmapFont.

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I thought Cocos2d a had default font or should I rather say CCMenu's was because I created a CCMenuItemFont object without specifying the font and it still appeared.